# Chrome issues with facebook and social apps

Tags: windows, facebook, google-chrome, social-networking

hope you're ok and having a nice and wonderful day.

I'm writing because I need some light with this issue and I can't point exactly to how to solve this.

I'm diagnosing an issue regarding google chrome opening social apps like facebook, X, instagram.  I thought that it was my firewall unit (Fortigate 500E in HA) that was blocking my users, but when I read the traffic using my FortiAnalyzer, I saw that traffic is not being blocked and it should be fine for my user to visit my these sites, since in the job description for my user as "Community manager" it should have access to those sites.

So, I run some test in their equipment, do the basics (ipconfig /flushdns, ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew, check switches, etc..) and this is what I found so far:  Using Internet Explorer and FireFox, the user can access the sites without problem, but with Chrome it cannot access the sites, it gets the ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSE.

If I open the inspection window within the browser, in the users computer, some elements from the browser loads, others with the ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSE message points me to CORS policies, and I'm pretty sure these policies are from a server side level, and what concerns me is that it only happens to chrome.

Does anybody has deal with this??  The chrome version I'm diagnosing is the most recent, downloaded from google's website (Chrome 122).

Hope you can point me in the right direction with this.

Comment: After a long diagnostic of this issue, I need just to confirm if there is some issue with nginx that can make possible that when a website is requested, it returns a white page.  In my config, I thought it might be a problem with my DNS, because it uses additional forwarders, such a s openDNS, but of the requested page, I can browse the top level domain.

Comment: For instance, the top level domain quieroaplicar.com  I can browse it from my terminal, but if I tried to navegate to usma.quieroaplicar.com, here I get the white page.  I thought it was my firewall, but if I can access the top level domain, logic tells me that I should access the subdomain as well.

Comment: I can access facebook, x and the other sites, but in other terminals, I get the white page, and this is only in chrome.